# Laravel generate forms with JSON

Tags: json, laravel

Is there a way in Laravel to save JSON code in one table field and when you load that JSON code you get generated form (view) where you can submit data that can be saved in JSON code and then again saved in one table field?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Redis.

```
$formData = Redis::set('formdata',$json);
$formData = Redis::get('formdata');
```